# Python & Firebase - Unable to Read Uploaded File in Storage

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload my file to my Firebase Storage.

Many months ago, I could add my files using my same method, now I can add but I can't see its preview and direct link.

My code is

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import storage

cred = credentials.Certificate('C:\\Users\\Wicaledon\\PycharmProjects\\ABC\\XXXXXX.json')
# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/',
    'storageBucket': 'XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com'
})
database_url = 'https://XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/'

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob2 = bucket.blob('my_image.jpg')
blob2.upload_from_filename('C:\\Users\\Wicaledon\\PycharmProjects\\ABC\\my_image.jpg')
```

I see my file now like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHCnL.jpg). I can't see its preview and link at the right side.

But I can add same file manually from my hand, and I can see its preview and link.

What is the problem? Can you solve it ?

Comment: I'm having exactly same issue.  But the file is successfully put on the storage. My client app can get the download url and display correctly. So this might be the issue with the firebase console.

Comment: @Bananadroid I saw that there is a link below the image preview to get access token. If you click and refresh the page, you see the picture, but the question is; why...